# Activity starts Remote service, Starts another activity and finish() initial activity. Is this a problem?

Tags: android

My initial activiy is basically a splash screen while preforming initialization and login in to network server.  To save memory I want to finish() the splash activity once it starts the main menu activity.  I still want the remote service to operate.  Testing shows it does.  But am I going to get into trouble doing this?

I know I can restart the remote from the main menu activity but I am trying to save overhead by not starting it twice.  The remote service is required by the splash activity.

Answer (score 1):

I don´t think you will get a problem. The service that you start with startService() will still be running and in the other activity you can use without a problem.
Here is an example and some doc:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html